# Getting rid of *consecutive* periods in a filename

Tags: c#

I was wondering how I'd get rid of periods in a filename if i have a filename like:

Test....1.txt to look like Test 1.txt ?  I do NOT want files like :  1.0.1 Test.txt to be touched.  Only files with consecutive periods should be replaced with a space.  Any ideas?

This is my current code but as you can see, it replaces every period aside from periods in extension names:

```
 public void DoublepCleanUp(List<string> doublepFiles)
    {
        Regex regExPattern2 = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
        Regex regExPattern4 = new Regex(@"\.+");
        Regex regExPattern3 = new Regex(@"\.(?=.*\.)");
        string replace = " ";
        List<string> doublep = new List<string>();
        var filesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        try
        {
            foreach (string invalidFiles in doublepFiles)
            {
                string fileOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(invalidFiles);
                string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileOnly);

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileOnly))
                {
                    string filewithDoublePName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(invalidFiles);
                    string doublepPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(invalidFiles);
                    string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(invalidFiles);
                    //string newName = name.Replace(".", " ");
                    string newName = regExPattern4.Replace(name, replace);
                    string newName2 = regExPattern2.Replace(newName, replace);
                    string filesDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(invalidFiles);
                    string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(invalidFiles);
                    string fileWithExt = newName2 + fileExt;
                    string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filesDir, fileWithExt);
                    System.IO.File.Move(invalidFiles, newPath);


                    DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
                    clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    clean.Cells[0].Value = doublepPath;
                    clean.Cells[1].Value = filewithDoublePName;
                    clean.Cells[2].Value = fileWithExt;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);
                }

                else
                {
                    if (filesCount.ContainsKey(fileOnly))
                    {
                        filesCount[fileOnly]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesCount.Add(fileOnly, 1);
                        string newFileName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileOnly),
                            filesCount[fileOnly].ToString(),
                            System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileOnly));

                        string newFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileOnly), newFileName);
                        System.IO.File.Move(fileOnly, newFilePath);

                        DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
                        clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                        clean.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                        clean.Cells[1].Value = fileOnly;
                        clean.Cells[2].Value = newFileName;
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
         //throw;
             StreamWriter doublepcleanup = new StreamWriter(@"G:\DoublePeriodCleanup_Errors.txt");
             doublepcleanup.Write("Double Period Error: " + e + "\r\n");
             doublepcleanup.Close();
         }

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string name = "Text...1.txt";   
Regex r = new Regex("[.][.]+");
string result = r.Replace(name, " ");
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, to do that with a string:

```
string st = "asdf..asdf...asfd...asdf.asf.asdf.s.s";
Regex r = new Regex("\\.\\.+");
st = r.Replace(st, " ");
```

This will replace any instance of 2 or more `'.'`s with a space.

I would throw this into a method:

```
public static string StringReplace(string original, 
                                   string regexMatch, string replacement) {
    Regex r = new Regex(regexMatch);
    return r.Replace(original, replacement);
}
```

Comment: @Struan, true.  This does fail in that case.  May just want to add a special case for it.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
string newFileName = String.Join(".", fileName.Split('.').Select(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? p : " ").ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like this?

```
string newName = name;
while (newName.IndexOf("..") != -1)
  newName = newName.Replace("..", "  ");
```

Comment: This will add a lot of spaces. For example "Test......1.txt" will have 3 spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use use regular expressions, something like this

```
string fileName = new Regex(@"[.][.]+").Replace(oldFileName, "");
```

Comment: your regix can be as simple as `"[.][.]+"`, and you should be replacing with a space instead of the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
static string CleanUpPeriods(string filename)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (filename.Length > 0) sb.Append(filename[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < filename.Length; i++)
    {
        char last = filename[i - 1];
        char current = filename[i];
        if (current != '.' || last != '.') sb.Append(current);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void ReplaceConsecutive(string src, int lenght, string replace)
{
    char last;
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder add = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char now in src)
    {
        if (now == last)
        {
            add.Append(now);
            if (count > lenght)
            {
                ret.Append(replace);
                    add = new StringBuilder();
            }
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.Append(add);
            add = new StringBuilder();
            count = 0;
            ret.Append(now);
        }
    }
    return ret.ToString();
}
```

Untested, but this should work.

`src` is the string you want to check for consecutives, `lenght` is the number of equal chars followed by each other until they get replaced with replace.
This is AFAIK also possible in Regex, but I'm not that good with Regex's that I could do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this code on a number of cases, and it appears to exhibit the requested behavior.

```
    private static string RemoveExcessPeriods(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return string.Empty;
        // If there are no consecutive periods, then just get out of here.
        if (!text.Contains(".."))
            return text;
        // To keep things simple, let's separate the file name from its extension.
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(text);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(text);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
        bool lastCharacterWasPeriod = false;
        bool thisCharacterIsPeriod = fileName.Length > 0 && fileName[0] == '.';
        bool nextCharacterIsPeriod;
        for (int index = 0; index < fileName.Length; index++)
        {
            // Includes both the extension separator and other periods.
            nextCharacterIsPeriod = fileName.Length == index + 1 || fileName[index + 1] == '.';

            if (!thisCharacterIsPeriod)
                result.Append(fileName[index]);
            else if (thisCharacterIsPeriod && !lastCharacterWasPeriod && !nextCharacterIsPeriod)
                result.Append('.');
            else if (thisCharacterIsPeriod && !lastCharacterWasPeriod)
                result.Append(' ');

            lastCharacterWasPeriod = thisCharacterIsPeriod;
            thisCharacterIsPeriod = nextCharacterIsPeriod;
        }
        return result.ToString() + extension;
    }
```

I just made a change to handle some edge cases. Here are some test results for this version.

```
"Test....1.txt" => "Test 1.txt"
"1.0.1..Test.txt" => "1.0.1 Test.txt"
"Test......jpg" => "Test .jpg"
"Test.....jpg" => "Test .jpg"
"one.pic.jpg" => "one.pic.jpg"
"one..pic.jpg" => "one pic.jpg"
"one..two..three.pic.jpg" => "one two three.pic.jpg"
"one...two..three.pic.jpg" => "one two three.pic.jpg"
"one..two..three.pic..jpg" => "one two three.pic .jpg"
"one..two..three..pic.jpg" => "one two three pic.jpg"
"one..two..three...pic...jpg" => "one two three pic .jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from dark_charlie's solution, isn't

```
string newName = name;
while (newName.IndexOf("..") != -1)
  newName = newName.Replace("..", ".");
```

enough?

Answer (score 1):

Combining some other answers...

```
static string CleanUpPeriods(string filename)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\.\.+");
    string s = regex.Replace(name, " ").Trim();
    if (s.EndsWith(".")) s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
    return s + extension;
}
```

Sample Output

```
"Test........jpg" -> "Test.jpg"
"Test....1.jpg" -> "Test 1.jpg"
"Test 1.0.1.jpg" -> "Test 1.0.1.jpg"
"Test..jpg" -> "Test.jpg"
```